# Get variable names from an lm object without segregating factor levels

Tags: r, linear-regression

I need to get variables names back form an `lm` model. `variable.names()` does fine except when one of the variables is a `factor`, in that case:

```
model <- lm(Petal.Length~Petal.Width+Species, data=iris)
variable.names(model)
```

returns:

```
"(Intercept)"       "Petal.Width"       "Speciesversicolor"        "Speciesvirginica"
```

I need the `Species`variable to appear only once, without specifying different levels for each factor, something like:

```
"(Intercept)"       "Petal.Width"       "Species"
```

Comment: You could do model$terms[[3]]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could extract the names with `all.vars` from the `call`, remove the last string which is the data.

```
all.vars(model$call)[1:length(model$call)]
# [1] "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"
```

Answer (score 3):

Get the `names` of the model's `model.frame`:

```
names(model.frame(model))
## [1] "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"
```

or use `terms`

```
all.vars(terms(model))
## [1] "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"
```